# Elasticsearch - 6.3.2

Tags: elasticsearch

Getting the below error for a specific Index, rest of the Indexes are fine. any help please

"textPayload": "[2021-04-13T08:40:07,629][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Encountered a retryable error. Will Retry with exponential backoff {:code=>400, :url=>"http://elasticsearch-elasticsearch-svc.name-space.svc.cluster.local:9200/_bulk"}\n",